# What's the Difference Between <s:property ..> and ${param}

Tags: jsp, syntax, parameters, struts2, struts

In struts I notice there are two different ways to access variables.  I am curious what the difference is and when to properly use each one.  For example, suppose we set the variable height like so:

```
<s:set var="height">300px</s:set>
```

Now I can use it two ways:

```
<div style="height: ${height}">&nbsp;</div>
```

..or..

```
<div style="height: <s:property value='#height' />">&nbsp;</div>
```

What is the difference, and which is better to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The struts2 `<property>` provides additional functionality beyond what `${}` offers, such as providing a default value if the variable is null, and control over HTML-escaping.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use ${} inside another struts 2 tag. You can not nestle struts tags inside each other.