# How to put Struts2 property value as a variable into query string in JSP?

Tags: jsp, struts2, query-string

The question is:
I can get  the property value from the action class using:

```
<s:property value="%{variable}" /></TD>
```

and now i want to put this variable into the query string like:

```
<a href="http://www.sample.com/sample.jsp?name=${variable}">Visit W3fools.com</a>,
```

but this format is for a plian JSP variable, which format i should use for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use the link with `${variable}`

Because `<s:property value="%{variable}" />` takes more time to execute.

See their [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1099933/778687)

Comment: thanks for your information, but i am asking how can i put the value from valuestack as a variable into jsp, since the value can only be got through Struts2 tag

Comment: no problem, you can go with `<a href="http://www.sample.com/sample.jsp?name=${variable}">Visit W3fools.com</a>` or you may prefer this - `<a href='http://www.sample.com/sample.jsp?name=<s:property value="%{variable}" />'>Visit W3fools.com</a>`

Comment: @user1055108 That is incorrect, S2 uses a request wrapper that allows access to value stack variables via JSP EL.

Comment: @tusar, last I looked OGNL was faster since ${} was checked after exhausting the value stack.

Comment: @Quaternion The wrapper checks the value stack first. If it's not found it then goes to scoped attributes. Using `${}` doesn't do any of the tag logic, either, it simply looks up the value. My gut reaction is that `${}` would be faster, but I haven't profiled to see if that's the case.

Comment: @Quaternion, I got that idea (`${}` is faster) from stackoverflow only. see the first comment on this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7185331/778687, not quite sure what to accept... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
  <s:url var="sample" value='http://www.sample.com/sample.jsp'>
      <s:param name="name"><s:property value="%{variable}"/></s:param>
  </s:url>

  <s:a href="%{sample}">Visit W3fools.com</s:a>
```